# Exclude anything inside double quotes in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I am doing my FYP and i am numbering all the blocks in any java code. My program takes a java code file as input then identify blocks inside it. like

```
class A{/*B1*/
  public static void all(){/*B2*/
    int a=10;
    /*B3*/if(a>10){/*B4*/

    }
  }
}
```

I have done all this but my problem is when `if`, `for` , `else` or any such word comes in double quotes my program gives a block to it as well while it should not as per my requirements. Now i just want to not number anything inside double quotes.

Comment: State machine is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

So change your scanning code (which you haven't posted so I can't be more specific) to ignore anything inside quotes. You will also want to ignore anything inside Java comments as well.

For example you could have a `boolean inQuote` that you set to true when you reach a quote mark and false when you leave it.

While `inQuote` is true then ignore anything you find.

Comment: Actually i am in office and unable to post code. But i am reading Java code line by line from a file. Now in a line there can be if(line.contains("if i am a boy")); now the starting if should be numbered as a block and the if in double quotes should not be blocked.

Comment: Yes, I understand your requirement - however there are hundreds of ways you could potentially be scanning the file, and several different options for each of those how to handle this case.